# Change Domain Problems

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have been trying to change the domain and have been running into issues. I hope someone can help me out here, I have documented the steps I went through below.

I requested the DNS resouuce from our dns admin team.

.mike-cf.company.com    canonical name = mike-cf.company.com.
Name:    mike-cf.company.com
Address: 10.52.88.123

I then installed with the -D switch:

bash < <(curl -s -k -B http ://raw.github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/master/dev_setup/bin/vcap_dev_setup -D mike-cf.company.com)

I noticed that not all the config files in ~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config changed, so I changed those using sed command:

$ cd ~/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config
$ sed -i 's/.vcap.me/.newdomain.com/g' *.yml

I restarted and things were looking good, I was able to run vmc target with no problem but I was not able to register a user.

$ vmc target http://api.mike-cf.company.com/
Successfully targeted to [http://api.mike-cf.company.com]

$ vmc register --email mike@company.com --passwd password
Creating New User: Error 100: Bad request

There was no entried in uaa.log only this in the cloud_controller.log

[2012-09-25 09:06:46.712110] cc - pid=20400 tid=8ee9 fid=4757  DEBUG -- ---> async\nrequest: post http://uaa.mike-cf.company.com/oauth/token\nheaders: {"content-type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "accept"=>"application/json", "authorization"=>"Basic Y2xvdWRfY29udHJvbGxlcjpjbG91ZGNvbnRyb2xsZXJzZWNyZXQ="}\nbody: grant_type=client_credentials
[2012-09-25 09:06:46.718338] cc - pid=20400 tid=8ee9 fid=4757  DEBUG -- <---\nresponse: 404\nheaders: {"SERVER"=>"nginx", "DATE"=>"Tue, 25 Sep 2012 16:06:46 GMT", "CONTENT_TYPE"=>"text/html", "CONTENT_LENGTH"=>"162", "CONNECTION"=>"close"}\nbody: \r\n404 Not Foundhttp://uaa.mike-cf.company.com: 404 trace ["/home/mike/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/uaa-dad29c9030f4/gem/lib/uaa/http.rb:56:in `json_parse_reply'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/uaa-dad29c9030f4/gem/lib/uaa/token_issuer.rb:157:in`request_token'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/uaa-dad29c9030f4/gem/lib/uaa/token_issuer.rb:128:in `client_credentials_grant'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/app/models/uaa_token.rb:80:in`access_token'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/app/models/uaa_token.rb:96:in `user_account_instance'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/cloud_controller/cloud_controller/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:13:in`create'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.14/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.14/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in`process_action'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.14/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.14/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in`block in process_action'", "/home/mike/cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/deploy/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `*run*_3844132275556875466__process_action_*2824786929479189233*_callbacks'"]
[2012-09-25 09:06:46.896386] cc_events - pid=20400 tid=8ee9 fid=4757   INFO -- [2012-09-25 09:06:46 -0700, :USER, "N/A", "POST:/users", "mike@company.com", :FAILED, "Bad request"]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem, there seemed to be an issue with the vmc I was using. Once I downgraded VMC I am now able to connect.

gem uninstall vmc

gem install --version '= 0.3.18' vmc

Here is the thread that lead me to the answer
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/vcap-dev/enY2qKnSJWI

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to see the content of the uaa config file? Make sure it has the correct IP address specified for the NATS message bus, the line should look something like this;

```
mbus: nats://nats:nats@192.168.1.10:4222/
```

If that IP address is incorrect, it needs to be changed. I take it the server it is installed on has a static IP address? was it assigned before you installed VCAP?

Comment: I am running it in a VM (VirtualBox) with Bridged DHCP, DNS resource for *.mike-cf.company.com in DNS server. The IP has not changed since I created the VM.  mbus: mbus: nats://nats:nats@10.52.88.132/ which is the right IP.  When changing hosts do I need to change all instances of vcap.me found in all the yml files under config?

Comment: Yes, definitely, there are still remaining config files with the vcap.me domain in them?